# Is it possible to use the adverb 'now' in the past?

Tags: adverbs, past-tense, past-perfect

I learn pluperfect in German and recently ran into a [web-page with English-German examples](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/perfect/PastPerfect.html). One of the example seems to me incorrect, so I am bringing this out to make sure I correctly understand the English grammar.

The sentence:

> I had already spoken Chinese as a child, but now I wanted to learn German.

seems to me grammatically incorrect because of *now* instead of ***then*** I strongly believe there must be ***then*** there, because *now* cannot be used in the past. Am I right or wrong? Is there any example of ***now*** in the past?

Comment: Yes, it's normal to use 'now' when referring to a time in the past _in relation to_ an earlier time.

Comment: Neither language would use the pluperfect because the two facts have no relation to each other. It's a poor example.

Comment: 'I had already spoken Chinese as a child' sounds unidiomatic per se. 'I spoke Chinese as a child, ...' or 'I had learned Chinese as a child, ...'.

Comment: The question suggested as a duplicate of this one has a very similarly worded header, but the specific usage of _now_ that the poster there asks about seems quite different from the specific usage that the poster here asks about.