# Can I use past tense in "now that" clause?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Can I use past tense in "now that" clause?

Is the following sentence correct?

> Now that Tony was no longer present, there was a distinct change in her attitude.

Comment: Yes. "Now" can be a reference in the past tense. It refers to a stratum of time in the present or past, and does not necessarily mean "the time that you are reading this line." But it can do that too: "Now that you have read the examples, try to write your own sentence using the vocabulary words provided in bold."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Now is the time" followed by past tense verb.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411769/now-is-the-time-followed-by-past-tense-verb) Also [Using 'now' with past tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/515470/using-now-with-past-tense) and [Is it possible to use the adverb 'now' in the past?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448391/is-it-possible-to-use-the-adverb-now-in-the-past), among others.

Comment: **The** past tense.  Perhaps you should consider posting on [ell.se].